# Find a String and extract the numbers that come after the string

Tags: python, string

I have a string as the following

```
{u'contentDescription': u'0 Minutes 3 SecondsElapsed3 Minutes 35 SecondsDuration', u'checked': False, u'clickable': False, u'scrollable': False, u'text': None, u'selected': False, u'enabled': True, u'bounds': {u'top': 1320, u'left': 48, u'right': 1032, u'bottom': 1386}, u'focusable': True, u'focused': False, u'checkable': False, u'longClickable': False, u'visibleBounds': {u'top': 1320, u'left': 48, u'right': 1032, u'bottom': 1386}, u'childCount': 0}
```

How to parse this string in python such that I get the numbers before the Duration and after Elapsed. i.e, 3.35.

It is seen on the first line of the string. 3 Minutes 35 Seconds. I want to extract only these numbers in the format 3.35.

Can you please guide me on how to do this? I am new to python. Thanks!

Comment: Show your own effort and code trying to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question). If you get stuck at a _specific_ issue, you can ask here.

Comment: Don't parse it as a string. Use `ast.literal_eval()` to convert it to a dictionary and then access the elements normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_str` is either the whole string or if you convert it to dictionary then it equals to `my_converted_dict['contentDescription']`:

```
''.join([val for val in my_str[my_str.find("Elapsed") + len("Elapsed"):my_str.find("Duration")].replace("Minutes", ".") if val.isdigit() or val == "."])
```